# Make cursor go transparent on timer (0.5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's the code, but instead of it completely disappears, is there some way to make it go 0.5 opacity? Help on this would be much appreciated.

```
$(function () {
var timer;
var fadeInBuffer = false;
$(document).mousemove(function () {
    if (!fadeInBuffer) {
        if (timer) {
            console.log("clearTimer");
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = 0;
        }

            console.log("fadeIn");
        $('.fade-object').fadeIn();
        $('html').css({
            cursor: ''
        });
    } else {
        fadeInBuffer = false;
    }


    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("fadeout");
        $('.fade-object').fadeOut()
        $('html').css({
            cursor: 'none'
        });
        fadeInBuffer = true;
    }, 2000)
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [fadeTo()](https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/). Hope this helps.

```js
$(function () {
var timer;
var fadeInBuffer = false;
$(document).mousemove(function () {
    if (!fadeInBuffer) {
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = 0;
        }
        $('.fade-object').fadeTo('slow', 1);
        $('html').css({
            cursor: ''
        });
    } else {
        fadeInBuffer = false;
    }


    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('.fade-object').fadeTo('slow', 0.5)
        $('html').css({
            cursor: 'none'
        });
        fadeInBuffer = true;
    }, 2000)
});
});
```

```css
.fade-object{
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fade-object"></div>
```

Comment: The cursor is still 100% transparent?

Comment: @JoalRoberts You cannot control the default cursor's opacity. Instead you can have your own cursor and you can define it's opacity. See, https://davidwalsh.name/css-custom-cursor

Comment: You ideas are false.

Comment: @JoalRoberts If you were able to change the opacity of the native cursor, please let me know. I want to know how you did that!

Answer (score 0):

** UPDATED **

Try using setInterval instead of setTimeout, and vary from 10 to 0 to disapear and from 0 to 10 to reapear (according to filenames).

Do this by changing trhough custom png cursors with alfas from 0 to 100 in 10 phases.

Here are some images I prepared:  [image: Opacity 100%], [image: Opacity 90%], [image: Opacity 80%], [image: Opacity 70%], [image: Opacity 60%], [image: Opacity 50%], [image: Opacity 40%], [image: Opacity 30%], [image: Opacity 20%], [image: Opacity 10%], [image: Opacity 0%] << last one is 0%

Remember that your cursor (mouse pointer) WON'T change its custom image IF it is NOT moving **, so .. you will need to translate cursor at least 10px programatically while iterating trhough the 10 images.

** UPDATE 2 **

Here you can feel the idea.
//codepen.io/jjyepez/pen/xEQAXZ

PS (forget about translating cursor .. it is not necessary whatsoever)

Comment: Please, use imgur to host images. Stack Overflow has a dedicated account to host them. It is accessed by the image icon in the editing tools (upper bar, visible when you write or edit an answer).

Comment: Here you have it coded.
http://codepen.io/jjyepez/pen/xEQAXZ

I think this is kind of what you are wanting (re-programmed).

Comment: PS: Take into consideration that custom cursors seem to be resampled before render so in some browsers they could look pixelated or even the alpha pixels maybe colored.